# "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown" when calling web service with Java

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm trying to call a web service with a Java client. The WSDL looks like this: http://pastebin.com/m13124ba

My client:

```
public class Client{
    public static void main(java.lang.String args[]){
        try{
            CompileAndExecuteServiceInterfaceStub stub =
                new CompileAndExecuteServiceInterfaceStub
                ("http://192.168.1.3:8080/axis2/services/CompileAndExecuteServiceInterface");

            Compile comp = new Compile();
            comp.setArgs0("Test");
            comp.setArgs1("public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(\"Hello\");}}");
            String[] classpath = {};
            comp.setArgs2(classpath);
            stub.compile(comp);

        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }

}
```

When I run the client now the following error occurs:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown


at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:517)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at de.dax.compileandexecuteclient.CompileAndExecuteServiceInterfaceStub.compile(CompileAndExecuteServiceInterfaceStub.java:184)
at de.dax.compileandexecuteclient.Client.main(Client.java:17)</blockquote>
```

I tried out the business logic of the server on my local machine and there it works. The service creates files and folders. Are web services allowed to do that? I also wrote a simple "Hello World" web service and deployed it to the server. This worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure you want classpath to be set as empty..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there was an NullPointerException in my service.

Answer (score 3):

When you get one of these "unknown" AxisFaults, definitely check the server log!  The client-side stack trace most likely will not be detailed enough for you to track down the error.

I believe dax is indicating above that he found the NullPointerException in the more-detailed server side stack trace.  It would look something like:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)

    [....]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    [....]
```

Comment: Well in my case its not hitting the webservice if its Object but it hits if its String. I have added question on this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859844/org-apache-axis2-axisfault-unknow-type-can-not-serialize-while-passing-array-of

Answer (score 1):

From the provided logs, I cannot determine what's wrong. Try to set the log-level of Axis2 to "debug" (see the two log-configurations in the root directory of your Axis2 installation) and check the details for the exact cause. Axis2 tends to be a bit sparse in propagating the errors coming from webservices.