# Axis2 Webservices responses unknown as falutstring with SoapUI

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, soapui

I have implemented and deploy Webservice using Axis on Tomcat 6.0, it's working with Java client generated with ADB(Axis2 Databinding Framework), since I need to avoid inner classes in webservice client.

```
1) I choose the xmlbeans axis client. but it didnt work returns Axisfault unknown
2) tested with SOAPUI and got the following response.

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

checked the following link here and enabled the axis log to TRACE and could not fine anything in the log as error, could anyone help on this ?

Thanks in advance

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882398/org-apache-axis2-axisfault-unknown-when-calling-web-service-with-java
```

following is the part of my detail axis log when request sent from soapUI

```
6928440022] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'SOAPActionBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Transport'
2015-11-07 20:34:00,094 [http-8082-2] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase  - [MessageContext: logID=urn:uuid:5D2DFFEB29EDBF25B4144
6928440022] Invoking flowComplete() for Handler 'RequestURIBasedDispatcher' in Phase 'Transport'
2015-11-07 20:34:00,095 [http-8082-2] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet  - OnDemandLogger initialized for class or
g.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet is:org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger@7bfb7cbb
2015-11-07 20:34:00,095 [http-8082-2] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet  - org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
2015-11-07 20:34:00,096 [http-8082-2] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper  - [MessageContext: logID=urn:uuid:5D2DFF
EB29EDBF25B41446928440022] isFaultRedirected: FaultTo is null. Returning isReplyRedirected
2015-11-07 20:34:00,098 [http-8082-2] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.addressing.AddressingHelper  - [MessageContext: logID=urn:uuid:5D2DFF
EB29EDBF25B41446928440022] isReplyRedirected: ReplyTo is null. Returning false
2015-11-07 20:34:00,098 [http-8082-2] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext  - messageID is null.
2015-11-07 20:34:00,099 [http-8082-2] TRACE org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference  - hasAnonymousAddress: http://www.w3.or
g/2005/08/addressing/anonymous is Anonymous: true
2015-11-07 20:34:00,100 [http-8082-2] TRACE org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference  - hasAnonymousAddress: http://www.w3.or
g/2005/08/addressing/anonymous is Anonymous: true
2015-11-07 20:34:00,107 [http-8082-2] TRACE org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine  - [MessageContext: logID=urn:uuid:5D2DFFEB29EDBF25
B41446928440175] sendFault:null
```

Comment: What is the problem? Don't say "it doesn't work", explain what doesn't work, what were you expecting and what you want to do in the end.

Comment: Thank you for the response.
1)  I created new SOAP project in SoapUI by giving WSDL URL,
2) Auto generated the Request, filled the necessary values and invoked.

I expected a console out in the method and return the result from WS, but nothing happened expect the above result as response.

thanks